# If the relative value of the most negative eigenvalue is small, can we view the quadratic program as convex?

Tags: convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming, positive-semidefinite, non-convex-optimization

Consider symmetric matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with $n-1$ negative eigenvalues and a positive one such that $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2> \dots > \lambda_n$, where $\lambda_n$ is the most negative eigenvalue of $A$.

Based on how I build $A$, there are cases where $\big|\frac{\lambda_n}{\lambda_1}\big|$ is really small (e.g., $10^{-4}$). If I have an optimization problem whose convexity depends on $A$ being PSD, can I treat it as a convex problem in such cases?

For example, to use convex solvers for a relevant quadratic minimization problem?

Comment: The phrase *convex optimization* suggests a minimization problem to be solved.  It makes it hard to convince me that negative eigenvalues can be ignored.

Comment: Is $A$ symmetric?

Comment: @kimchilover: yes, i can make it symmetric if it helps anyhow!

Comment: No, consider the problem $\min_x x^TAx$. Many solvers use a cholesky decomposition, which will fail too.